# PHP $_GET parameters give issues

Tags: php, windows, post

Hi: I don't understand where I'm making errors, I'm calling fopen with an url

I have this function that should do POST requests:

```
    function do_post(string $url, $params=""): string {
       
        $options = array( 
            'http' => array(
                'header'  => "Length: ".strlen($params)."\r\n"." Content-Type: application/json\r\n",
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => $params
            )
        );
      
      $context = stream_context_create($options);

        
        $fp = fopen($url,'rb',false,$context);
        if(!$fp) {
            throw new ErrorException("post error - fopen");
        }
        
        $ret = @stream_get_contents($fp);
        if(!$ret) {
            throw new ErrorException("post error - get contents");
        }
        
        return $ret;
    }
```

I call it like:

```
do_post('http://127.0.0.1:9191/dummyresource/DUMMYOUT.php?user=u1&status=ON');
```

But I got this error:

> fopen(http://127.0.0.1:9191/dummyresource/DUMMYOUT.php?user=u1&status=ON):
> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 411 Length
> Required

I also added this line just before the fopen call but does nothing:

```
    $url = str_replace('&amp;', "&", $url);
```

How could I fix?

EDIT:
tested with `Content-Length`

I got

> PHP Warning:
> fopen(http://127.0.0.1:9191/dummyresource/DUMMYOUT.php?user=u1&status=ON):
> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use the cURL functions or Guzzle. (and stop using `@` to suppress potentially useful error messages)

Comment: I think the `411 Length Required` is trying to tell you something

Comment: @frz3993 shouldn't this: `"Length: ".strlen($params)."\r\n"` piece of code fix?

Comment: @ceejayoz @ is needed because otherweise it's output will ruin the cumulative json response

Comment: Well, that's the error you got. Start from there, probably the header  should be Content-Length

Comment: @frz3993 tested also with that, but I still bad-request (and still get dumb &amp; in the query string... which I suppose is what leads to bad request)

Comment: 400 Bad Request is different from 411. That is a different problem. What do you mean you still get dumb &amp; in query string? `fopen` won't suddenly url encode the string. I don't know what `DUMMYOUT.php` is expecting, you should look in the error log of the server that is serving that script. Might have some clues

Comment: @DDS Like I said, use something like Guzzle and you don't have to worry about such things. It's the gold standard for making HTTP requests in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion